# Prevent toolbar popup window from disappearing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I use a toolbar-button-popup-window, with the list of last focused window tabs. A click on some list item sets that tab to active via chrome.tabs.update(I don't know another way to do that). After that click popup window disappears. I would like to keep it visible, at least until a click outside that window. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There actually is one way - open developer tools for popup.html, but this is not the best workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but it looks like the answer is to use a background page.  This link might help:  http://mycodefixes.blogspot.com/2012/02/building-chrome-extensions-from-scratch_27.html.

I'm new to extensions as well so if anyone else knows of a better way let me know!